# restoring postgres database in postgres by multiple user at a time

Tags: postgresql

I had maintained a PostgreSQL database server in a Linux system. I was restoring a database into that system and my friend also tried to restore another database in the same system while i was restoring the database. He tried multiple times to restore but the restore was not completed. Once my restore was completed then only his restore was completed. Is there any other way to restore different database at the same time?

Comment: Did you wrap the whole restore operation in a transaction?

Comment: how to do that sir?

Comment: what pg_restore options did you use?

Comment: i simply used pgadmin to restore the database with default options